# How to Ack/Nack with reactive RabbitListener in Spring AMQP?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp, project-reactor, spring-rabbit

I'm using Spring AMQP 2.1.6 for consuming messages with a `RabbitListener` returning a `Mono<Void>`. For example:

```java
@RabbitListener
public Mono<Void> myListener(MyMessage myMessage) {
    Mono<Void> mono = myService.doSomething(myMessage);
    return mono;
}
```

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#async-returns) it says:

> The listener container factory must be configured with AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL so that the consumer thread will not ack the message; instead, the asynchronous completion will ack or nack the message when the async operation completes.

I've thus configured the container factory with `AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL`, but it's not clear to me whether "the asynchronous completion will ack or nack the message when the async operation completes" means that this is handled by `spring-amqp` itself or if this is something that I have to do? I.e. do I have to the ack/nack the message after the call to `myService.doSomething(myMessage)` or does Spring AMQP automatically ack's it since I'm returning a `Mono` (even though `AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL` is set)?

If it's the case that I need to manually send ack's or reject's, what's the idiomatic way to do this in a non-blocking manner when using the `RabbitListener`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listener adapter takes care of the ack when the Mono is completed.

See `AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.asyncSuccess()` and `asyncFailure()`.

**EDIT**

I am not a reactor person but, as far as I can tell, completing a `Mono<Void>` does nothing so the `on...()` methods are never called.

You can ack the delivery manually using `channel.basicAck` or `basicReject`...

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "foo")
public void listen(String in, Channel channel,
        @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the Mono returns Void afaict?

Comment: I think `doOnTerminate()` should work before returning that `Mono` from listener method.

Comment: @Gary Yes this works, but couldn't this be regarded as a bug / feature request for spring amqp? Or is there a reason for why it shouldn't work for Mono<Void> out of the box? Should I add an issue and potentielly even a PR?

Comment: It's out of our control - if Reactor doesn't call us, what can we do? I just submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/1005) to handle the situation if an async result is completed with a `null` value, but there's nothing he framework can do it reactor doesn't call us. I think Artem's suggestion is to add a `doOnTerminate()` to the Mono to call `basicAck` when it completes. Maybe we could detect a `Mono<Void>` result and add the `doOnTerminate()` in the framework. I'll discuss with Artem when he is back next week.

Comment: A non-null return type is intended for request/reply messaging; we didn't anticipate the `Mono<Void>` case. Feel free to submit a PR.

Comment: I think we need to change our `MonoHandler` to apply slightly different `subscribe()` model. That one which performs a `completeConsumer` for the `ACK` instead of `consumer` which is not called when there is no event in `Mono` to produce.